# ie11 compatibility with html a-tag

Tags: internet-explorer, hyperlink, cross-browser

Website is working quite well in all other browsers I have tested: FF, Opera, Safari, Chrome, safari ios. Of about 30 links I have on my home page not a single one will open in ie11, including none of the links in the drop down nav menu. **the page just refreshes**.

This is a site built mostly using bootstrap.

Here are a few different examples of links that are not working:

```
<a href="people/join_volunteers.php" class="btn btn-ghost btn-primary btn-lg text-theme"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>Volunteer</a> 

<div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
  <div class="list-inline social-icons-menu-top pull-right"> 
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/nosacares" class="social-hover-v1 a-facebook"></a>
   <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=key" class="social-hover-v1 a-youtube"></a> 
  </div>
 </div>

 <li> <a href="http://mywebsite.org/community/press_archives.php">Press Archives</a> </li>
```

When I run the dev tools, and test these links a couple different errors come up that seem like they could be relevant:

DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching.
HTML1300: Navigation occurred. (this one will pop up a few times for each click)

I would have figured this would be a very common problem but my searching has not found anything that has worked yet, nor anyone that has had an entire site break in ie like this.

Some other thing to note: My hta file is empty, I'm running default server settings from my hosting company. The page has a lot of js and jquery but it's tucked down at the bottom and all the js seems to be working fine.

I'm up for any suggestions here, including what the best way to test this in the dev tools would be?

Comment: I suggest you break down the whole site to a single link and then step by step remove additional components that aren't needed so you can see what component causes this.

Comment: Did you accidentally turn on any "compatibility mode" or another "browser mode" in IE?